# Can RabbitMQ allow Management UI to use OAuth and AMPQ connections to use Basic Auth?

Tags: oauth, rabbitmq

I've recently configured a local instance of RabbitMQ to work with an OAuth provider for authenticating users to the Management UI. That part of the authentication config is working, however the configuration setup required for this appears to have had an impact on the basic authentication of connections to RabbitMQ over AMPQ.

Below is the config for the RabbitMQ instance:

```
[
    {rabbit, [
        {auth_backends, [rabbit_auth_backend_oauth2]}
      ]},
    {rabbitmq_management, [
        {disable_basic_auth, false},
        {enable_uaa, false},
        {oauth_enabled, true},
        {oauth_client_id, "D9BXNFPta...."},
        {oauth_provider_url, "https://.....auth0.com"}
        ]
    },
    {rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2, [
        {resource_server_id, <<"rabbitmq">>},
        {extra_scopes_source, <<"permissions">>},
        {key_config, [
          {default_key, <<"qbDkJxa_....">>},
          {signing_keys,
            #{<<"qbDkJxa_....">> => {pem, <<"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
....
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----">>}
             }
      }]
    }
  ]}
].
```

The error on connecting with basic auth is:

`PLAIN login refused: Authentication using an OAuth 2/JWT token failed: provided token is invalid`